# How can I read data, (specifically a date and a time) from an excel sheet, concatenate the two values, and convert them to Unix Timestamp?

Tags: javascript, excel

example of the date and time

[image]

I'm trying to run a code that can take these two values from an excel sheet, date and time, and combine them to be displayed in Unix Timestamp. To be fully honest I have no clue what I'm doing, and have been asking ChatGPT for the code, which has proved to be more harmful than helpful.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQh5N.png)

This is what I've gotten after asking ChatGPT for a while.

This code is unable to display both the date and time properly (date being time1 and time being time2).

My result for the date is "45131" for the date of 7/24/2023, and I'm receiving null for the time. I haven't gotten started on trying to combine them, as all previous attempts have made the code run worse.

Answer (score 1):

You can sum two columns in Excel (date + time), then you will get a number of days from 1 January 1900 up to date. For 7/24/23 9:31:01 you will get 45131,39654 (if you see data/time just apply number format). The whole part 45131 means number of days which have passed from 01/01/1900 and fraction means fraction of the day. Also you need to substract one day from the total number of days, as Excel considers 1900 to be leap year. Since Unix time state is number of seconds elapsed from 01/01/1970, you may apply arithmetic operation.

Comment: Is that possible for you to ammend Excel file?